# Compute distance between fields on the same model in GeoDjango

Tags: django, geodjango

I want to compute the distance between two fields on the same model in GeoDjango. Here is the way I'm trying to do it:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(ref_location,D(km=F('i_move'))
```

Where location is a PointField and i_move is a float. However, this does not work, with django throwing :

> float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'F'

I also tried to get first the distance with a large number, than annotate, and after that compare the distance to the field:

```
Post.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(ref_location, D(km=100))
                                          ).annotate(distance=Distance('location', ref_location)
                                            ).filter(distance=F('i_move'))
```

This simply does not work, no error are thrown.

I could'nt find anyone doing something similar, though I think the issue is not recent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's not possible to do it the traditionnal way using F field lookup. I ended up using extra query parameters, and the [St_Distance_Sphere](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ST_Distance_Sphere.html) function of postgres, which is actually very good as it returns the distance in meters:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(....).extra(
   where=['ST_Distance_Sphere(location::geometry, ST_GeomFromText(%s)) <= i_move*1000'],
   params=[ref_location.wkt])
```

ref_location is a django Point(), location is a PointField, and i_move is a float. Django Points have a wkt method to get their wkt representation. However, as the ST_Distance_Sphere takes to geometry object, location should be converted using the postgres cast "::", and ref_location using the [ST_GeomFromText](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) function.